# Poor-quality video playback from YouTube

Tags: video, vlc, youtube

I have compiled from source codes player VLC 2.0.5
The build succeeds. But when playing video from YouTube playlists , I get problems.
Some videos are played perfectly. Others - no.
**bad** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LM0ee-BA9Z0&list=PLG1pJqRQs6GcEK7BBmchlDucco_o98HPv&index=1

http://farm03.photoload.ru/data/89/d2/66/89d266657a65bb9cb8de7752ca674a28.png?h=VdG86lmei_5RgIx5eVeQoA&t=1365333289

**Perfectly**
http://farm03.photoload.ru/data/fe/61/86/fe6186866ab4d4dd236b01a8b89cd6cd.png?h=2G7sY3XNJw12sWtF0Optjg&t=1365333363

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWjgyFvZ2OA

Prompt please the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to uncheck "Hardware acceleration" in the settings you get by right clicking on the Video.

That solved problems I had with YouTube videos a few times now.